# Extracting Data from two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

Table 1.

```
Name         Grade   Math  
---------------------------    
Chris          A      30
Julie          AA     35
Ross           AA     32
```

Table 2

```
Name       English
-------------------------    
Julie      29
Chris      22
Ross       20
```

I want to get the sum of the scores for English of students with AA grade for their math. How can I do that? Please help.

EDIT: I want to get the sum of English Scores of students with AA grades for Math, i.e for Julie and Ross: sum of English scores would be 29+20.

Comment: post the output you want

Comment: This looks like homework to me. Have you tried anything yourself? There are many ways to achieve this. Show us some effort and we give you alternatives :-)

Comment: You should also tell us about your tables. What are the primary keys? This is essiential to know in order to build the right queries. For instance the one answer given so far works great when both tables' primary key is name, but may show a wrong result otherwise.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner this is a simplification of much complex assignment, and I need this trick to complete that assignment. I have been sitting for around 12 hours, and I am completely confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT Sum(B.English) Total
FROM   #Table_1 A
JOIN   #Table_2 B ON A.Name = B.Name
WHERE  Grade = 'AA'
```

If you want the marks separately use this

```
SELECT A.Name,
       Sum(B.English) Total
FROM   #Table_1 A
JOIN   #Table_2 B ON A.Name = B.Name
WHERE  Grade = 'AA'
GROUP  BY A.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT SUM(t2.English)
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.Name = t2.Name
WHERE t1.Grade = 'AA'
```

Comment: It tells me that multi-part identifier t2.English could nto be identified

Comment: You need to change it to match your column and table names.

Comment: @L.G: This is a very, very basic join. One of the first things you learn about SQL. You should be able to understand it and spot the error yourself. When you are told that t2.English could not be identified, how could you not come up with the cause for this error message yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The straigh-forward way to get data from one table where something is given in another table is to use EXISTS or IN.

```
select sum(english)
from table2 t2
where exists
(
  select *
  from table1 t1
  where t1.name = t2.name
  and t1.grade = 'AA'
);
```

With IN:

```
select sum(english)
from table2
where name in
(
  select name
  from table1
  where grade = 'AA'
);
```

I like IN much better here, but that's a matter of taste.

Both queries assume that both tables' primary key is name. I asked you to tell us, but you didn't. So again: With another primary key, you might need other queries.